# Need help setting up virtual surround sound on Logitech G430

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've googled and googled, looked through tons of results, but I can't seem to get anything to work.  I've looked into everything I can find, looked into pulseaudio along with alsa, and even OSS (But I can't find much on it, however I think that it might be the better way to go).  I really don't know where to go here, but I really want virtual 7.1 audio like I had on Winderp$.

Logitech has their own gaming software on Winderp$ that does this excellently, but for obvious reasons this isn't helping my issue.  I doubt wine would help, but if it would someone let me know.  I really want a fix to this, and as long as it can be done, I'll do whatever it takes.  Thank you for your time and answers.

Also, I do not believe this is a standard sterio device, as it's still ONLY using my front speakers on Linux, and whenever I do not have the Logitech Software installed on Winderp$.  If it's only using my front two speakers (or at least front channels), then my device must have been made in a way to where it's borderline actually 7.1 and not entirely virtual.  Also, running

> speaker-test -c 8

Uses all channels properly in the proper positions except for LFE.  I had to do a little configuring to get it to do this, but everything still thinks this is just a sterio device.  I think this is proof enough that my request is possible.

Even if it was just virtual, I still want a way to fix it and get 7.1 back.

This is the result of lsusb -v:

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0a4d Logitech, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        16
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0a4d 
  bcdDevice            1.19
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          253
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength          100
        bInCollection           2
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
        baInterfaceNr( 1)       2
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            13
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             1
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 6
        bSourceID              13
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls( 1)      0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            12
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      4 (MIXER_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 9
        bNrInPins               2
        baSourceID( 0)         12
        baSourceID( 1)          6
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        bmControls         0x00
        iMixer                  0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 1
        bSourceID               9
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls( 1)      0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls( 2)      0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            14
        wTerminalType      0x0301 Speaker
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               1
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID              13
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls( 1)      0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (SELECTOR_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 8
        bNrInPins               1
        baSource( 0)            2
        iSelector               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID            10
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               8
        iTerminal               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink          12
        bDelay                  1 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                14
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            0 Continuous
        tLowerSamFreq        8000
        tUpperSamFreq       48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x00c0  1x 192 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink          10
        bDelay                  1 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                14
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             1
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            0 Continuous
        tLowerSamFreq        8000
        tUpperSamFreq       48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0062  1x 98 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      43
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0005  1x 5 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

Comment: Please show the output of `lsusb -v` for this headset.

Comment: I will add this in an edit to my main post now, as it's too long to add here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plain stereo device.

The virtual surround effect is implemented by Logitech's Windows software.

PulseAudio has `module-virtual-surround-sink`, but it's [almost](http://xblog.hellokitty68.main.jp/?eid=1017366) undocumented.

Comment: Edited my post again, read what I said up there and the command I tested.

Comment: This device does not allow sending more than two channels to it. What configuring did you do?

Comment: I edited either a pulseaudio or a alsa config file and told it that this device had 8 channels.  Somehow the test works but nothing can use it.

Comment: What config file? What change?

Comment: I'll see if I can find it again, but to be honest I'm not sure.  I'll look through my previous terminal commands and see if it's there still

Comment: Found it.  /etc/pulse/daemon.conf is what I edited.  I edited default-sample-channels and made the number 8.  The test then displayed all channels except for LFE.  So again, this is proof that it's halfway working, and for sure possible.

Comment: PulseAudio then automatically downmixes to two channels.

Comment: So how can I fix this?  Is it alsa that is using the sound-test or is that pulse?

Comment: The default ALSA output goes through PulseAudio.